# Good verb for "to fall over forwards"?

Tags: expressions, verbs

I'm looking for a verb that describes falling over forwards - for example, if you're setting on a chair and someone shoves you from behind. What's the proper word to use here?

Thanks a lot!
Nicolas

Comment: "I'm looking forward a verb that describes falling over forwards": please fix this.

Comment: If there were such a verb, why do you think the phrase "fall over forwards" came into being?

Comment: In some contexts, faceplant would work. http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/faceplant

Comment: Sorry for the typo, fixed it!

Comment: Michael Harvey, so "fall over forwards" works? I'm familiar with the expression, I just wondered if there's a more eloquent to say it. "Faceplant" is probably too modern/cartoonish.

Comment: _Stumble_ might work when describing walking, but you can't stumble from a chair...

Comment: @MikeHarris You can certainly stumble from a chair. Actually, some assertions allow you to stumble without moving at all. *While sitting motionless I stumbled upon the idea of just not doing anything ever again.* *The old man stumbled from the chair and died.*

Comment: You can *topple* out of a chair.

Comment: @mama - I’m with MikeHarris here. stumbling connotes falling or nearly falling due to a misstep or uneven footing. I don’t see how one stumbles (literally) while sitting in a chair.

Comment: @mama  - stumbling *from* a chair means he got up out of the chair and immediately thereafter began to stumble

Comment: @Jim You can imagine that the world works in whichever way that makes you happy. It doesn't mean that it works that way, though.

Comment: @mama - Yes, you can :-)

Answer (score 2):

*Topple* might be your best bet.
Definition: to fall forward, as from having too heavy a top; pitch; tumble down.
(https://www.dictionary.com/browse/topple)

Answer (score 1):

Your best non-slang option would be ***tumble***

> Fall suddenly, clumsily, or **headlong**.

<sup>*([oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tumble))*</sup>

> Nicolas *tumbled* from the chair when his sister pushed it

"Tumble" is also transitive, so you can also say

> Nicolas's sister *tumbled* him from the chair.